# PHP inserts record via MYSQLI, but always gives error in echo

Tags: php, mysqli

Just having a little problem when inserting a record into my MYSQL table. The data goes in fine however I keep getting an error when the code queries to see if the entry was made.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO testtable (fnhusband,fnwife,surname,email,address,suburb,city,postcode,region,number,altnumber)
VALUES ('$fnhusband','$fnwife','$surname','$email','$address','$suburb','$city','$postcode','$region','$number','$altnumber')");

if (!mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
  {
  die('Error:' . mysqli_error());
  }
else { 
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

Comment: Cool, what is the error?

Comment: Delete $connect from query check and show us result please.

Comment: You are effectively doing this: `mysqli_query($connect,mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT...."));`, the first (inner) succeeds, the second fails.

Comment: You're using `mysqli` just like `mysql`, and it would be **very** easy to SQL inject your code. Look into **prepared statements**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming $connect is the link:

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

try changing

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO testtable (fnhusband,fnwife,surname,email,address,suburb,city,postcode,region,number,altnumber)
VALUES ('$fnhusband','$fnwife','$surname','$email','$address','$suburb','$city','$postcode','$region','$number','$altnumber')");
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (fnhusband,fnwife,surname,email,address,suburb,city,postcode,region,number,altnumber)
VALUES ('$fnhusband','$fnwife','$surname','$email','$address','$suburb','$city','$postcode','$region','$number','$altnumber')";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
```

or procedural:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (fnhusband,fnwife,surname,email,address,suburb,city,postcode,region,number,altnumber)
VALUES ('$fnhusband','$fnwife','$surname','$email','$address','$suburb','$city','$postcode','$region','$number','$altnumber')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Worked like a charm.